# Find geographic data on the languages spoken in Russia

Tags: language, census, russia

Does anyone have any ideas for where I can get data on the number or percentage of speakers of a given language in the Russian Federation at some geographic level smaller than federal subject?

Preferably, the data should come from the 2010 census.

Answer (score 1):

The 2010 Census results [are available](http://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/perepis2010/croc/perepis_itogi1612.htm) on the FSSS web site.

One should click on the *Построить таблицу по итогам ВПН-2010* link in the left menu. The direct link is [this](http://vpnmicrodata.gks.ru/webapi/jsf/tableView/tableView.xhtml#), but referrer should be in the *gks.ru* domain.

Here below an example table which contains data on Tatar language speakers in my native town (~100 000 people) and in suburbs.

[image: Novouralsk]

In the table above:

- *Родной язык* — native language (question 9.3 from the [questionnaire](http://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/perepis2010/croc/Documents/Vol1/l1.pdf))
- *Используемый язык 1, 2, 3* — 1st, 2nd and 3rd used languages (question 9.2)
- *Татарский* — Tatar language.

There is an Excel export capability.

---

Tables [7](http://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/perepis2010/croc/Documents/Vol4/pub-04-07.pdf) and [9](http://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/perepis2010/croc/Documents/Vol4/pub-04-09.pdf) of volume IV contain data by federal subject, and only most popular in a given federal subject languages are included.

Comment: How did you get the table to show up? When I pressed the 'tabulate' button, all I got was a small table with the population of Russia in it.

Comment: [User manual](http://vpnmicrodata.gks.ru/webapi/help-croc/superweb2_user_guide_CSH.pdf) (in Russian). In the left menu, check what you want to add to rows, then press «Add to... row» (or «Добавить к.. строка» in Russian). Then check all that you want to add to columns and press «Add to ... column» («Добавить к ... колонка»). Then check all that you want to add to subcolumns and press «Add to ... column» («Добавить к ... колонка») again, etc. If you want to remove a row or a column, check it in the left menu, and press «Remove» («Стереть»).